# OS X 10.10.5 and Windows 7 file sharing

Tags: windows-7, cross-platform, osx-yosemite, file-sharing

So what I want to do is share files between windows 7 pc and Macbook Pro Yosemite 10.10.5 using ethernet.

I managed to make it work really easily in the past but now it doesn't.

I have looked a bunch of tutorial online,I changed sharing settings,I have changed the settings of the ethernet adapters infinite times(manual ip,same subnet mask).I have restarted both computer a dozens times each, I have modified the register LmCompatibilityLevel with the values 1-4 with no luck.
After my fresh install of Windows 7 I managed to connect to windows PC from the macbook with the Go to Server tool over WiFi on the other hand the windows pc still can't see my macbook and on the network settings the LAN connection is displayed as "Unidentified".

I have no clue what I should do.At this point I just look at forums,tutorials and follow them blindly.
Maybe there is a third party program that could help me?

[ Windows 7 32 & 64bit(I tried both) , MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2009) ]

Answer (score 0):

I run Yosemite 10.10.5 on a 2013 Macbook.  I got here researching a floating-point calculation issues I seem to be having with the Mac, running some machine-learning software.

I have to share files among various Windows machines, the Macbook (running 10.10.5), and a bunch of different Linux boxes.  To make it seemless and simple, I've put ssh and scp on all of them, and just use "scp" to copy files between any pair if machines or devices. "scp" stands for "secure copy".  You can also use "ssh" (secure shell) to log into one machine from another.

The syntax for scp looks like this:

```
scp myfile_here.txt  MyUserID@SYSTEMname:/home/MyUser/filedir/.
```

The above command, which you enter in "cli" (command line interface) mode (basically just a terminal window or a Windows CMD shell), will securely copy "myfile_here.txt" over to the machine called "SYSTEMname", and put it into directory "/home/Myuser/filedir/".  The little dot just means give it the same name.  Instead of SYSTEMname, you can also use the numeric address of the machine (in either IPv4 or IPv6).  On a windows machine, you can go to CMD shell, and type: "ipconfig /all" to get the machine's IP address.  On the Macbook, you can click the little wifi indicator, then select "Open Network Preferences", click "Advanced", click "TCP/IP", and get the IPv4 address of you Macbook. OR, start up a "Terminal" window, and enter "ifconfig", and look at what is says for "en1". So then, the 'scp' command becomes:

```
scp myfile_here.txt  MyUserID@nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:/home/MyUser/filedir/.

 where nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn  might be something like 192.168.112.170
 or whatever number you need to use (this example is an IPv4 style number)
```

I think scp and ssh might be included on the Macbook.  If not, then maybe you have to download the "command line utilities" from Apple, which you can do, if you install the "Xcode7.2.1" C language compiler from them (it is free.)  Google around and you can find a link.

To get ssh and scp on a Windows-7 machine, you need to install the Cygwin stuff. (See link below).  You will also need to have the OpenSSH package, which may be installed as part of Cygwin.  I put a link to a site that explains this.  Check lots of sites.  Don't just blindly install stuff without understanding exactly what it is doing.  There is a real learning curve here, but it is worth spending the time to climb it.

If you get a Raspberry PI or jailbreak an old iPad, you can put the same ssh and scp programs on them, and then share files (including big video and music files) using these same programs.  You will need to spend some time learning Linux stuff (the programs and the various utilities), but it will be time well spent, if you plan to do any work with computers and modern devices.  Just google-search "ssh and scp" and read.

If you are using an older windows box (maybe you need to get some files off it), you can try "putty", which is just a graphic interface for the scp and ssh utility programs.  Here are some URLS:

Putty:  http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/software/ieee/

SSH:    https://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Windows

Linux ssh and scp:   https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/ssh-and-scp-howto-tips-tricks/

SSH and SCP on Windows-7:  https://www.question-defense.com/2010/01/07/how-to-install-scp-and-ssh-on-windows-7-using-cygwin

Just read this below.  I think you have to enable ssh and scp on Mac OSX to get it to work.  Apple has it turned off by default, but you can turn it on.  Here is a site that explains this:

http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/30/remote-login-ssh-server-mac-os-x/

Hope this is helpful.